# Axis tick marks for forestplot in R

Tags: r, plot, range, r-forestplot

I have a plot made with forestplot in the rmeta package.  Notice the horizontal axis has no tick marks.  How could I add them at, say, intervals of `0.5`?

Here is the plot:[image: plot]

And the code:

```
Forest1 <- read.table(file="Forest_1.txt", sep="\t", head=TRUE, row.names=1)

tabletext<-rbind(c("A","3.77"),
             c("B","1.33"),
             c("C","1.32"),
     c("D","1.12"),
     c("E","1.58"),
     c("F","0.9"))
m <-Forest1$OR
l <-Forest1$lower
u <-Forest1$upper

#overview datafile:
cbind(tabletext, m,l,u)
                          m      l        u       
[1,] "A"         "3.77" "3.77" "0.6144" "6.9256"
[2,] "B"         "1.33" "1.33" "0.644"  "2.016" 
[3,] "C"         "1.32" "1.32" "0.6536" "1.9864"
[4,] "D"         "1.12" "1.12" "0.4536" "1.7864"
[5,] "E"         "1.58" "1.58" "1.0116" "2.1484"
[6,] "F"         "0.9"  "0.9"  "0.7236" "1.0764"

forestplot(tabletext,m,l,u, zero=1, xticks=c(0.2,7),col=meta.colors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```

Comment: If you mean numbers under the x axis, then in function forestplot(), you can try to replace xticks=c(0.2,7), with xticks=c(0.2,seq(0.5,7,0.5))

Comment: Thanks Didzis, that works fine for me! :)

Comment: @DidzisElferts: That should probably go into the answer box...

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your call of forestplot with the following :

```
forestplot(tabletext,m,l,u, zero=1, xticks=c(0.2,.7,1.2,1.7,2.2,2.7,3.2,3.7,4.2,4.7,5.2,5.7,6.2,6.7,7),col=meta.colors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue", summary="royalblue"))
```